# What is the dimension of the kernel of a linear transformation from $P_1$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $T(p)=p(0)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that any $p\in P_1 = ax+b$.

So we're trying to find when $T(ax+b) = 0$ to get the kernel of $T$.

$T(ax+b) = a(0)+b = b$

So we have that $T = 0$ when $b = 0$. Does this mean the kernel of $T$ is $0$ dimensional (i.e. $\ker T = \{0\}$)?

Comment: Wouldn't the kernel include $\frac{-b}{a}$? (i.e. have dimension 1?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication is false. $Tp = 0$ if and only if $b = 0$ really means $Tp = 0$ if and only if $p = ax \in \text{span}(\{x\})$. Therefore $\text{ker}(T) = \text{span}(\{x\})$ has dimension 1.